# AkkaCluster: Terminated vs MemberRemoved message

Tags: scala, akka-cluster

I am using akka clusters and having trouble figuring out when to use the Terminated message to figure out that a member has left the cluster vs using the UnreachableMember/MemberRemoved message. What is the difference between the 2 messages and some example use cases?

Answer (score 0):

`MemberRemoved` is a **cluster event**, that member completely removed from the cluster.
You can [subscribe](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-usage.html#subscribe-to-cluster-events) to change notifications of the cluster membership by using `Cluster(system).subscribe`.

On the other hand, there is a [DeathWatch](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/supervision.html#what-lifecycle-monitoring-means), a mechanism to watch an actor to check if it is terminated. When DeathWatch is used, the watcher will receive a `Terminated`(watched) message when watched is terminated.